# Use Ubuntu & Windows in the same network and make share file

Tags: networking

I work in a company that all of computers have Windows OS and we faced a lot of problems because of that ,now we want to migrate to Linux os like ubuntu , as our work is monitoring each person have to use 4-5 Computer , 1-2 of them should be windows because we use some  application which doesn't support Linux(they are exe files ) how we can use one keyboard and mouse and link them to eachother?! Would you please introduce the application?!
in the other hand each team should share their data each hour ,,,previously we used file share in windows but if we use both (ubuntu & windows ) is there any program that could help us?! 
 Thank you in advance

Comment: You want to use remote desktop, or filesharing?

Comment: We want share an excel file and each team should fill related part and after some calculation get a number ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a program called TeamViewer. It should allow you to access multiple different desktops, share files, and even troubleshoot other people's problems. The link is below. I think they have an enterprise/commercial/workplace solution.

[TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com)

Comment: Dear Andrew Thanks for your kind response actually as i know team viewer is not suitable for File sharing (just some excels ) but i will recheck the site